# Can I host a nextjs app on ubuntu VPS and with apache2

Tags: apache, next.js, vps

I am trying to deploy a Nextjs app in my ubuntu vps and I have apache2 as my virtual host. Can I deploy using apache or there is any other better methods

Comment: I think it can help you. [link](https://dev.to/aanis434/how-to-deploy-a-react-nextjs-application-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-in-aws-ec2-instance-221o)

Answer (score 0):

you can install pm2 in your vps
and then you can start
expecting you have following scripts in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
```

}

after building the project by `npm run build`
and then
`pm2 start "npm start -- -p Port" --name name-of-process`
(replace 'Port' and 'name-of-process' with correct values, and make sure you are inside the project folder before running the commandes)

Comment: Thank you very much. After running can I set a domain to my app using apache

Comment: yes, you can, you have point A reocrds of your domain to the ip address, and it should work

Comment: what is name-of-process?

Comment: what ever you want to name it.

Comment: I keep getting same error in logs - (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (localhost:3000) failed.
by project folder you mean .next , right?

Comment: not inside .next, try to do it where your package.json is located